# Switching from VGA to Display Port makes text blurry

Tags: display, resolution, vga, displayport

I have seen users connecting two monitors to the same computer experience different text appearance on the two monitors.My PC i could say is experiencing the same issue, i have a single PC and a single monitor, when my PC was connected over VGA, the text was crispy and sharp and not fuzzy or blurry until i changed from VGA to Display Port, I did this to fix a black background shadow blur with white text the VGA analog to digital signal conversion the monitor was doing. But then my text over the Display Port is really fuzzy and not so sharp. I think my system unit believes i have two monitors connected and is downgrading the optimum visual experience out through the Display port,The onboard graphics card is `Intel HD graphics 2500` and the monitor model is `Lenovo L2251 wide`.
How can i resolve the fuzzy text on my PC? I have tried researching on how to change primary display output from VGA to Display Port with no success, please help

Comment: Is the cable DisplayPort both on PC and display end? What resolution is the display running at? What is its native resolution? I can't find `L2251` on Google, it's just either L2251X or L2251P.

Comment: Yes the cable is both DP male to male(at both ends), the resolution of the display{maximum} is 1680*1050

Comment: Its the `l2251p`

Comment: What resolution is it actually set to?

Comment: 1680*1050 @75Hz

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases the resolution is set too low or only one end of the cable is actually DisplayPort and a crappy adapter is the culprit. We've ruled these out in the comments.

Your ClearType settings may be incorrect and the VGA noise could've masked the problem until now. Search for *"Adjust ClearType"* in the Start menu. The wizard will guide you through the process.

Comment: Lemme try,but i agree the adapter is the one messing it all up

Comment: Clear type didn't change anything, perhaps i should go tom adapter monitor and tv settings?

Comment: That's weird. With DisplayPort there's not much more going on, since you're sending a digital video signal over digital link to a digital display. Can you post a photo of the blurry text?

Comment: Okay, actually am gonna send a sample over VGA and another one over display port

Comment: Actually even the screenshots i took and stored on my pc while using VGA have a blurry effect thanks to windows

Comment: I bet this is a system software problem

Comment: Image Link https://i.imgur.com/mninAUR.png

Comment: Its not even effective to send an image because your system will make it look better, your bitmap scaling

Comment: That's why I'm specifically asking for a _photo_, not a screenshot. The screenshot you've posted looks blurry, but that's because it's already scaled down by your photo viewer.

Comment: If its blurry ten that's what i need corrected

Comment: The visual experience on edge is better than on firefox

Comment: Am installing a new OS to investigate if its OS messing up

Comment: Sorry, without the photos there's nothing I can do to help you. I've ran out of generic ideas and wanted to see what it exactly looks like. Screenshots do me no good because they will most likely all look the same.

Comment: Hey, i uninstalled the adapter and got crisper text over Microsoft Basic Display driver..The adpater is messed up

Comment: So there _was_ an adapter? My first question was if both the monitor and the PC are connected using DisplayPort, and you said "yes"... but if there's an adapter then the answer should've been "no", at least one end is not connected using DisplayPort but through an adapter.

Comment: The adapter am referring to is the onboard `intel hd graphics`, i disable it from the  device anager and zoom text to 125%, everything is good looking and crisper. Still the connection is DisplayPort to DisplayPort

Comment: Okay, that's not what we usually call an "adapter" except in very particular contexts. You've enabled scaling now, so it's not an apples to apples comparison anymore. That doesn't tell us if it's actually HD Graphics' fault, and that would be very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue and noted in the Advanced Display Settings for the monitor that was blurry, the Active signal resolution was less than the Desktop resolution.

This post fixed it for me > https://superuser.com/a/1470967/1163967.

You need to go into "Display adapter properties for display", click "list all modes", select anyone, then change it back to correct display. Worked perfectly for me!